# SoundCloud's client ID

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, soundcloud

I want to make a client-side tool involves SoundCloud API, however they no longer let you register to get your key.

After playing around with the site a bit, I found that you can still make public api request with the `client_id` from the api requests when i am on the site.

So my question is: is it okay to just slap that `client_id` into my tool? Will it be prone to any attacks/security issues?

At the moment, I only know how to extract it manually. If anyone knows how to retrieve that as you access the site, please let me know. I'd be much appreciated.

Comment: You could use php or javascript to make a request to soundcloud and then read it's client id or simply embed an iframe which does not even require a client is then.